# Image Verification in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am totally new in jQuery and I am trying to make a Image Verification in my project there are four images and four answer boxes, user simply arrange the correct image in correct box when all image and answer boxes match user "Match". I try some codes but it could't work. My codes are here.

```
<img id="ans1" src="icon/folder.png" />
<img id="ans2" src="icon/magnifier.png" />
<img id="ans3" src="icon/recycle.png" />
<img id="ans4" src="icon/trash_empty.png" />

<div id="answer1"></div>
<div id="answer2"></div>
<div id="answer3"></div>
<div id="answer4"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$('img').draggable({ containment: 'document', revert: true, drag: function(){
var image = $(this).attr('id');
}});  

$(document).ready(function() { 
$('div').droppable({containment: 'parent', drop: function(image){
var answer = $(this).attr('id');
 if(answer=='answer1' && image=='ans1'){
     alert('Image match.'); 
}else{
    alert('Condition not working!');
}
 }});

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/khizar067/2men9/

Comment: **Java !=javascript**. Please do not confuse with tags.

Comment: I once heard: Java is to javascript what car is to carpet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image object is event, so you must use (ev,ui) to get the object you are dragging, ui.draggable is the object you are dragging

```
$('div').droppable({
    containment: 'parent',
    drop: function (ev, ui) { 
       //               ^^
        console.log(ui.draggable);
        var answer = $(this).attr('id');
        if (answer == 'answer1' && ui.draggable[0].id == 'ans1') {
         //                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            alert('Image match.');
        } else {
            alert('Condition not working!');
        }
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/2men9/3/)